# Service Broker required port

Tags: sql, sql-server, service-broker

Does anyone know if there is a port that absolutely has to be open on the SQL server to allow service broker traffic? We were testing what happens when you close off all ports on the SQL server except (1433, 445, 3389) and the query notification still worked. We were under the impression that 4022 has to be open for the service broker to work we a default listening port.

Is there a SQL system view that shows what port the service broker is communicating on?

Is there a command to terminate all active query notifications on a database so the database can be dropped?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your service broker architecture is passing messages between servers (endpoints) then it will need ports other than the normal SQL ones.

If client code such as query notifications is accessing service broker then it uses SQL statements (with some new syntax) through the standard SQL connection and this part doesn't use any additional ports.

Comment: We are using standard ADO.Net code to receive sql dependency notifications, so it sounds like it uses the standard sql port for communication. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

From [How to: Activate Service Broker Networking (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166113.aspx):

> Service Broker does not send or receive messages over the network by
>   default. To activate Service Broker networking in an instance, create
>   an endpoint for Service Broker.

When you create an endpoint you specifically assign a port to use:

```
CREATE ENDPOINT BrokerEndpoint
    STATE = STARTED
    AS TCP ( LISTENER_PORT = 4037 )
    FOR SERVICE_BROKER ( AUTHENTICATION = WINDOWS );
```

Port 4022 is used when Service Broker communicates with other broker instances. How are you using Service Broker? If all the work is internal to your database then it never needs to use a TCP endpoint.

Comment: To get this to work we enabled broker services on each database we wanted to use and then from each server we use to connect to the database we call SQLdependency.Start() (.NET). I have not had to run the previous create endpoint statement on any of my environments to get the SQLDependencies to work. Am I missing something with regards to how SQLDependency uses the service broker?

All we want to do is have our servers establish sql dependencies and then have sql raise events when the underlying data changes. So far it works, but I just need to find out answers to my previous questions. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Query Notification does not require a Service Broker endpoint because it always deliver the messages locally, int he same DB where you started the notifications from. Although configuring QN to deliver notifications to a remote machine is *possible*, ding so is basically unheard of. See [The Mysterious Notification](http://rusanu.com/2006/06/17/the-mysterious-notification/).

As for the question: Service Broker requires only the configured endpoint port to be open. You can see the listening port in [`sys.tcp_endpoints`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177572.aspx). *If* the configured authentication is Windows then the ports needed for Kerberos/NTLM (135, ?389) are also required in order to authenticate the SSB connections. Note that the SMB port (445) is *not* required by SSB ever. If SSB endpoint configured authentication is certificates then no additional port is required. See [How does Certificate based Authentication work](http://rusanu.com/2008/10/23/how-does-certificate-based-authentication-work/).