# Cannot find the object "QueryNotificationErrorsQueue" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr.client, sqldependency

I am using `SqlDependecy` with `signalR` to push notifications to client browser  when there is some database changes, I followed [this](http://techbrij.com/database-change-notifications-asp-net-signalr-sqldependency) and [this](http://venkatbaggu.com/signalr-database-update-notifications-asp-net-mvc-usiing-sql-dependency/) post and everything works fine in local `SqlExpress` version 11.0  with  Local Connection String , but i have some kind of  permissions problem when i connect to remote database hosted in GoDaddy with Production Connection String

**Working Local ConnectionString**

```
<!--<add name="NotifyConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString=
"Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=TestDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;" />-->
```

**Production ConnectionString**

```
<add name="NotifyConnection" connectionString="Server=000.00.00.000;Database=TestDB;
User Id=UserName;Password=YourPassword;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

**Get Data Method**

```
public IEnumerable<Order> GetData()
{

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
["NotifyConnection"].ConnectionString))
{

using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
{

command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

command.CommandText = "SELECT OrderID,CustomerID FROM dbo.[RestUser]";

command.Notification = null;

SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);

if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
connection.Open();

using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
return reader.Cast<IDataRecord>()   // Here the Error throws
       .Select(x => new Order()
       {
       OrderID = x.GetInt32(0),
       CustomerID = x.GetInt32(1)                   
       }).ToList();


 }
 }
 }
```

**What i have tried ?**

I followed this [post](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/156991-using-sqldependency-to-monitor-sql-database-changes/) to Grant permissions in sql server , but not sure is this correct method to follow.

```
USE YourDatabaseName;

CREATE QUEUE NameChangeQueue;

CREATE SERVICE NameChangeService ON QUEUE NameChangeQueue ([http://schemas.microsoft.com/
SQL/Notifications/PostQueryNotification]);

GRANT SUBSCRIBE QUERY NOTIFICATIONS TO YourUserName; // Here i get this error:

//Cannot grant, deny, or revoke permissions to sa, dbo, entity owner, information_schema, 
  sys, or yourself.

ALTER DATABASE YourDatabaseName SET ENABLE_BROKER;  // Broker is already enabled
```

**Screen Shot:**

[image]

I am new to `SqlDependency`, how to fix this issue ?

Any help would be great.

Comment: Check out the networking and authentication considerations in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8316200/707618). Also, where in your code are you calling [`SqlDependency.Start()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.start(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: @Smudge202 Thanks for the comment, I am calling  it in `Appliaction_Start` , and we are planning to move to azure, but in azure  `SqlDependency` is not supported so we get [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33693020/azure-sql-server-error-statement-receive-msg-is-not-supported-in-this-version) error, planned to use to [triggers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9880091/monitor-data-changes-in-sql-azure) to track database changes with signaR, any better suggestions ?

Comment: Personally, I'm not a big fan of either SqlDependency nor Trigger approaches. Instead, I would consider publishing messages to a Service Bus (or queue of some form). One listener can persist the data to the database (as I'm sure you're doing now), whilst another listener can handle your SignalR push notifications. It not only solves this issue but gives you a layer of resilience against service outage. That's how I'd approach it, but I understand that doesn't resolve your SqlDependency problems directly, sorry.

Comment: @stom Hi i am facing the same issue. same requirement same problem. did you fixed this bug ?

Comment: @Narasappa, I had issue with Go daddy database server, in shared hosting they restrict some features, are you using shared hosting ? and trying to show notification with signalR ?

Comment: @stom thanks. we too using GoDaddy shared server.. Any solution for this problem ?

Comment: @Narasappa , one solution for using `SqlDependency` is getting dedicated server in Godaddy which will have all permissions or I have posted my solution check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38587725/2218697) to send notification without `SqlDependency`, i have used asp.net mvc, hope you get some idea, Let me know your solution.

Answer (score 0):

In shared hosting because they restrict some features, so i was unable to use `SqlDependency`, but here is my solution to **Play notifications without SqlDependency** in asp mvc

If you are new `signalR`, then first try [this](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-and-mvc) post to create simple chat web application.

My requirement was to play notifications when new sales happens in shops

**1. Create SignalR Server Hub**

SignalR server hub class that sends messages to all clients browser.

```
[HubName("PascalCaseNewSalesHub")]
public class NewSalesHub : Hub
{

    public void Send(string shopid)
    {
        // Call the alertNewSalesToPage method to update clients.

        Clients.All.alertNewSalesToPage(shopid);
    }

}
```

**2. Javascript Send Method in PlaceOrder View**

When a customer places new order for this shop then the following javascript code Calls the Send method on the server hub to update clients.

```
<script>

$(function () 
{
// Reference the auto-generated proxy for the hub.
var chat = $.connection.PascalCaseNewSalesHub;

var thisShopID = @(ViewBag.ShopID);


// Start the connection.
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {

// Call the Send method on the hub to send this shops ID

chat.server.send(thisShopID);


});
});
```

**3. Javascript Client Call Back Method in ShopSales View**

The hub class on the server calls this javascript function to push content updates to each client.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () 
{

console.log('Page loaded');

// Declare a proxy to reference the hub.

var notifications = $.connection.PascalCaseNewSalesHub;

if (notifications != null)
{
 console.log('connected to SalesHUB proxy');
}

var thisShopID = @(ViewBag.ShopID);

// Create a function that the hub can call back to alert new sales.

notifications.client.alertNewSalesToPage = function (shopid)
{
// check if sales happened for this shop then play notification

if (shopid == thisShopID) 
{

 var sound =new Howl({
          src: ['../sounds/rings.mp3','../sounds/rings.wav','../sounds/rings.ogg',
          '../sounds/rings.aiff'],
          autoplay: true,
          loop: true
          });

          sound.play();

          $('#loading').show();

          // Partial View to Update LatestSales for this Shop

          $("#new-Sales").load('@Url.Action("GetLatestSales", "Shop")')

          $('#loading').hide();

          console.log('New Sale happened, Notification Played');
        }

    };


    // Start the connection.
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {


        console.log('signalR connection started');


    }).fail(function (e) {
        alert(e);
    });
});



</script>
```

Used `Howler.js` Plugin to play notification , check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38571639/2218697) post.

Hope helps someone.