# SqlDependency in GoDaddy

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, shared-hosting

Is SqlDependency not working on GoDaddy? I'm trying to listen to a database table whenever a data change is done a particular process should be executed.

Everything is working fine in my development machine. But when I deploy it to GoDaddy it doesnt work and no error is being fired.

I'm having problems in this line

```
var dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you make sure your deployment machine has no permission issues with the url you are trying to access ?

Comment: Nice tip there. I found this when I tried access the url

Comment: Cannot find the object "QueryNotificationErrorsQueue" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.

Comment: It does exists. Does GoDaddy restricts users from using query notification?

Comment: I don't have anything else useful to help with, but make sure you check the links that pop up upon googling for your error message, such as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38456433/cannot-find-the-object-querynotificationerrorsqueue-because-it-does-not-exist)

Comment: Still, pay attention to the fact that the error **may be** caused by lack of permissions, as the error message states: "... does not exst **or you do not have permissions**"

Comment: I think its a permission isssue. Will try some approach. Thanks!

Comment: It is indeed a permission issue. I tried exposing my database over the internet and it works. But using GoDaddy's DB doesnt let me to. I can't even execute ALTER DATABASE statements in GoDaddy. Thanks.

Comment: I would then close this question and open another one addressing the security issue.